# Выбор нескольких строк из 2 таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть у меня 2 таблицы: users и user_params

Пример таблицы users:

```
id | name
1  | Vasya Pupkin
2  | Pupok Vaskin
```

Пример таблицы user_params

```
uid | param_int
1   | 10
1   | 20
1   | 30
2   | 10
2   | 25
```

Как мне выбрать данные так, чтобы конечный результат выглядел следующим образом?

```
id| name         | params
1 | Vasya Pupkin | 10,20,30
2 | Pupok Vaskin | 10,25
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
  users.id,
  users.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    user_params.param_int
    ORDER BY user_params.param_int ASC
    SEPARATOR ',') AS params
FROM
  users
  LEFT JOIN user_params
    ON users.id = user_params.uid
GROUP BY
  users.id;
```

Comment: Отлично! То что надо, спасибо! Я в принципе подозревал что это как-то делается через функции вроде concat, но про group_concat не слышал. Спасибо большое!